# how to break out of "if" block in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, break

How can I break out of an **if** statement?

**Exit** only works for "for", "sub", etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VB.net:

```
if i > 0 then
   do stuff here!
end if
```

In C#:

```
if (i > 0)
{
  do stuff here!
}
```

You can't 'break out' of an if statement.  If you are attempting this, your logic is wrong and you are approaching it from the wrong angle.

An example of what you are trying to achieve would help clarify, but I suspect you are structuring it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such an equivalent but you should't really need to with an If statement. You might want to look into using Select Case (VB) or Switch (C#) statements.

Answer (score 2):

In C# .NET:

```
if (x > y) 
{
    if (x > z) 
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.Writeline("cool");
}
```

Or you could use the [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2(VS.71).aspx) statement.

Comment: Also you could throw an exception and catch it outside of `if`. Or just terminate the process :)

Comment: Regarding the `goto` command, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
bool result = false;
if (i < 10)
{
    if (i == 7)
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: the code does not compile, stating that there is no loop to break out of

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, that in some cases you really wanna have something like an exit sub or a break. On a rare occasion is I use "Goto End" and jump over the "End If" with the def. End:

Answer (score -3):

I know this is an old post but I have been looking for the same answer then eventually I figured it out

```
        try{

            if (i > 0) // the outer if condition
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Will work everytime");
                if (i == 10)//inner if condition.when its true it will break out of the outer if condition
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Will only work when the inner if is not true");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // you can add something if you want
        }
```

`

Comment: bad idea to use exceptions for flow of control. They're slow.

Comment: Adding to what @KateGregory said, exceptions should only be used when the program enters a rare, error, or unexpected state. 

Using exceptions for means of flow control is harder to read, confusing, and less understandable for others.

Comment: better use `Exit Try` (VB), may be `break` in C#